# How to get FTP server's file separator

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am using `FTPFile` class and I did not find any method or variable which shows the path separator as we do in `Files` class (`File.separator`). How can we get the file separator of ftp server using java.Is there any predefined variable or method in `FTPFile` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no API for an FTP client to tell remote path separator, not only in Java Apache Commons, but in general.

Though, most decent FTP servers will use `/`, even if the actual remote OS use a different separator.

But the FTP specification does not mandate it. So there are indeed FTP servers that use a different separator. Like the OpenVMS FTP server (mainframe FTP servers in general).